# Paypal - What does "dirty" mean in the SDK version string?

Tags: paypal

When using Paypals native SDK, and calling it's version method, I get this printed to the debug output window:

```
2.0.0-dirty
```

Why does "dirty" get printed and what is it's meaning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

> Why does "dirty" get printed and what is it's meaning?

It means that when we build version 2.0.0 of our PayPal iOS SDK, we performed two steps in the wrong order. ;)

The mistaken inclusion of `-dirty` is purely cosmetic, and the SDK is fine to use.

However, the day after posting version 2.0.0, we corrected our mistake and posted [version 2.0.1](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases).

We always recommend using the latest version of our SDKs. You can stay informed about updates by "watching" our [github repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK).